# Word for splitting something into two parts and joining them together using a new element

Tags: single-word-requests

Here are some examples I can think of:

1. Cutting wire in half and adding extension in the middle joining up to each halfs.
2. Adding a pressure meter segment to an exisiting pipe.
3. Inserting an instruction into an existing fetch/execute pipeline.

Examples:

If a verb

"We will need to ___ between the controller and actuator subsystems"

or if a noun

"We will need a ___ between the controller and actuator subsystems"

Closest word I can think of is "tap" but that doesn't quite cut it for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! What a good question! For single-word-requests we recommend adding a sentence with a gap for the requested word to make the question clearer. An example might be "When I poke a jelly and it makes a wavy motion, it is ___.", to which the answer might be "wobble".

Comment: See if [joint](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/joint) works. It's both a noun and a verb. Look up synonyms if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best word I can think of for the generic case is ***[splice](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/splice)***:

> 1. to join together or unite (two ropes or parts of a rope) by the interweaving of strands.
> 2. to unite (timbers, spars, or the like) by overlapping and binding their ends.
> 3. to unite (film, magnetic tape, or the like) by butting and cementing.
>      <sub>*definition from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/splice)*</sub>

In your specific examples, a little bit of extra verbage may be required:

> We will need to *splice an extension* into this wire
>   We're going to *splice* a pressure meter segment into this run of pipe

This is mostly using sense 3 from the definition above, where we are first creating new ends of our wire or pipe, then joining each end to the new element.

(Because an instruction pipeline is not really physical and has no significant cost for placing a new entry between other entries, "splice" doesn't really seem to apply; simply "inserting" seems fine.)

Answer (score 1):

Many technical subjects in order to reduce ambiguity expect the right word

**Tap** is perfectly correct for inserting a measurement meter mid way between joints.
If opting for a more expensive **replacement** of the segment with a meter then that's that.

If you need to **renew** a segment of cable as you would use **two splices**.

For steel its a single or **double spliced joint.**

To **inject** an instruction that's what you need to say you do.

The only form of singular commonality is the above cases is you **add** an **addition.** or *attach* an *attachment*

Answer (score 1):

You need an **intermediation** of some kind between the cut pieces.

The word [intermediate](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/intermediate) has a variety of meanings, but they all refer to something in between two other things.